# yarn start - "error Command failed with exit code 2. "

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, node-gyp

I'm trying to start my project with `yarn start` as usual, but today I got this error :

```
error Command failed with exit code 2. 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

These are the steps i tried to solve this error:

- delete `node_module` folder;
- delete `yarn.lock`;
- delete `package-lock.json`;
- run `yarn cache clean`;
- run `yarn install`;

this is the output of 'yarn install':

```
yarn install v1.22.19
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning redux-devtools-extension@2.13.9: Package moved to @redux-devtools/extension.
warning uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
warning @testing-library/react > @types/testing-library__react > @types/testing-library__dom@7.5.0: This is a stub types definition. testing-library__dom provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning @types/classnames@2.3.1: This is a stub types definition. classnames provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning @types/redux@3.6.0: This is a stub types definition for Redux (https://github.com/reactjs/redux). Redux provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/redux installed!
warning apollo > cli-ux@6.0.9: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning apollo > apollo-language-server > apollo-datasource@3.3.2: The `apollo-datasource` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
warning apollo > apollo-language-server > apollo-server-errors@2.5.0: The `apollo-server-errors` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
warning apollo > cli-ux > @oclif/screen@1.0.4: Deprecated in favor of @oclif/core
warning apollo > @oclif/plugin-autocomplete > @oclif/core > @oclif/screen@3.0.4: Deprecated in favor of @oclif/core
warning apollo > apollo-language-server > @apollo/federation@0.27.0: The @apollo/federation package is deprecated and will reach end-of-life September 22, 2023. It contains outdated utilities for both running subgraphs and composing supergraph schemas. Please migrate to the appropriate package for your use case (@apollo/subgraph or @apollo/composition). For more details, see our announcement blog post (https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/backend/announcing-the-end-of-life-schedule-for-apollo-gateway-v0-x/) and documentation (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federation-2/backward-compatibility/#is-official-support-ending-for-apollogateway-v0x).
warning apollo > apollo-language-server > apollo-datasource > apollo-server-env@4.2.1: The `apollo-server-env` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/utils.fetcher` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
warning bundle-stats-webpack-plugin > @bundle-stats/cli-utils > @bundle-stats/html-templates > recompose > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor@6.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/flame@7.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/bubbleprof@5.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > insight > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/clinic-common@4.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/flame > @nearform/clinic-common@4.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/bubbleprof > @nearform/clinic-common@4.0.0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/node-trace-log-join@2.0.0-0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/bubbleprof > @nearform/node-trace-log-join@2.0.0-0: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/trace-events-parser@1.0.4: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/bubbleprof > @nearform/trace-events-parser@1.0.4: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/node-trace-log-join > @nearform/trace-events-parser@1.0.4: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning clinic > insight > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning clinic > insight > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning clinic > insight > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/clinic-common > browserify > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning clinic > @nearform/doctor > @nearform/clinic-common > brfs > static-module > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
warning clinic > @nearform/flame > 0x > nanohtml > transform-ast > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
warning eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
warning node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning node-sass > node-gyp > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
warning optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-functional-notation > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
warning react-styleguidist > buble > os-homedir@2.0.0: This is not needed anymore. Use `require('os').homedir()` instead.
warning react-styleguidist > buble > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
warning react-styleguidist > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
warning react-styleguidist > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
warning react-styleguidist > copy-webpack-plugin > webpack-log > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-styleguidist > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
warning react-styleguidist > buble > acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0: This is probably built in to whatever tool you're using. If you still need it... idk
warning react-styleguidist > remark > remark-parse > trim@0.0.1: Use String.prototype.trim() instead
warning resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning stylelint > @stylelint/postcss-css-in-js@0.37.3: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning stylelint > @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.2: Use the original unforked package instead: postcss-markdown
warning terser-webpack-plugin > cacache > @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
warning webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > slick-carousel@1.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=1.8.0".
warning "apollo > apollo-language-server > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-interface@2.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".
warning "apollo > apollo-language-server > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-interface > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-parser@2.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".
warning "apollo > apollo-language-server > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-interface > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-types@2.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".warning "apollo > apollo-language-server > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-interface > @apollographql/graphql-language-service-utils@2.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".
warning " > babel-plugin-styled-components@1.13.3" has unmet peer dependency "styled-components@>= 2".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.x".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/parser@2.x".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-eslint@10.x".
warning " > loadable-ts-transformer@1.0.0-alpha.3" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@^3.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/8] ⠄ waiting...
[8/8] ⡀ node-sass
[3/8] ⡀ @newrelic/native-metrics
[-/8] ⡀ waiting...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "C:\\Users\\myself\\Documents\\Projects\\MyProjects\\rct-fe\\node_modules\\@newrelic\\native-metrics: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./lib/pre-build.js install native_metrics
Arguments:
Directory: C:\\Users\\myself\\Documents\\Projects\\MyProjects\\rct-fe\\node_modules\\@newrelic\\native-metrics
Output:
============================================================================
Attempting install in native-metrics module. Please note that this is an
OPTIONAL dependency, and any resultant errors in this process will not
affect the general performance of the New Relic agent, but event loop and
garbage collection metrics will not be collected.
============================================================================

> C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe C:\\Users\\myself\\Documents\\Projects\\MyProjects\\rct-fe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js clean configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\\Python27\\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\gyp\\\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\@newrelic\\\\native-metrics\\\\build\\\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\.node-gyp\\\\14.18.1\\\\include\\\\node\\\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\.node-gyp\\\\14.18.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\.node-gyp\\\\14.18.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\@newrelic\\\\native-metrics',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\@newrelic\\\\native-metrics\\\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok
> C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe C:\\Users\\myself\\Documents\\Projects\\MyProjects\\rct-fe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js build -j 4 native_metrics
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/t:native_metrics',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64',
gyp info spawn args   '/m:4'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
gyp ERR! command \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\" \"C:\\\\Users\\\\myself\\\\Documents\\\\Projects\\\\MyProjects\\\\rct-fe\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\bin\\\\node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"-j\" \"4\" \"native_metrics\"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\\Users\\myself\\Documents\\Projects\\MyProjects\\rct-fe\\node_modules\\@newrelic\\native-metrics
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 692.80s.
```

- re-run `yarn start`;

But i get the same error message.

i'm using:
node : v14.17.2

Comment: Could you post more about the error? There isn't info here to see where the error originates from.

Comment: Thank you @AkshayGupta, i update my post with the output of 'yarn install' command where i get some errors too.

Comment: do you have visual studio 2019 installed?

Comment: In the meantime i tryed to update node to v14.18.1

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, it is

Comment: does this actually exist? `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: This path exists: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild" but i have only 2 folders in it : "Current" and "Microsoft". I will try to reinstall Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: try running 'yarn start' with the '--verbose' flag to get more detailed output on what might be causing the error